# WPF - Running CMD opens console window with wrong path

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a a small WPF app that will help me run JMeter tests in non-GUI mode without the hassle of typing JMeter commands and file paths into the console every time I want to run a test. This means that my WPF app needs to open up CMD in location where my JMeter is intalled and then pass an argument (command line).

This is how I open up CMD with a specific path and arguments I pass:

```
private void RunScript()
    {
        var process = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WorkingDirectory = "@D:\\Programi\\apache-jmeter-5.1\\bin",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/K jmeter -n -t " + scriptDirectoryPath
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
```

As you can see, the path where the CMD needs to open is "D:\Projekti\JMeteor\JMeteorApp\JMeteorApp\bin", but the path in CMD is "D:\Projekti\JMeteor\JMeteorApp\JMeteorApp\bin\Debug>"

[image]

How do I remove the "Debug" portion in CMD path? I tried switching solution configuration to "Release" but that just replaces "Debug" with "Release" in path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not write the `@` inside the string

use either

```
WorkingDirectory = "D:\\Programi\\apache-jmeter-5.1\\bin"
```

or (I guess you wanted to use the `@` for a verbatim string)

```
WorkingDirectory = @"D:\Programi\apache-jmeter-5.1\bin"
```

Comment: @BrianRasmussen No worries, I will in a few minutes because the website has a time restriction on when an answer can be accepted as solution.

Comment: Thanks - didn't mean to nag.